# Change value of div depending on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand how to change the value of a div by using {{model_value}}. What I have is a tad bit more complicated. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-control" ns-show="runningImport" disabled="disabled">
    {{input[row.header_safe]}}{{select[row.header_safe] != 'Add Attribute'))
</div>
<select class="form-control"
    ng-model="select[row.header_safe]"
    ng-options="option for option in row.options"
    ng-hide="select[row.header_safe] == 'Add Attribute' || runningImport"></select>
<input class="form-control"
    ng-model="input[row.header_safe]"
    ng-show="select[row.header_safe] == 'Add Attribute'"
    ng-hide="runningImport"
    placeholder="{{inputPlaceHolders}}"
    ng-required="select[row.header_safe] == 'Add Attribute'"
    ng-readonly="runningImport"/>
```

If my `<select>` has `Add Attribute` selected, it hides, and shows the input field. I want to update the `<div>`'s content to show the value of `<select>` UNLESS it's `Add Attribute`, in which case the `<input>` value should be shown.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use two divs.

One for showing the input-content if 'Add Attribute' is selected. And the other when not 'Add Attribute' is selected.

```
<div class="form-control" ng-hide="select[row.header_safe] == 'Add Attribute'">
    {{select[row.header_safe] != 'Add Attribute'))
</div>
<div class="form-control" ng-show="select[row.header_safe] == 'Add Attribute'>
    {{input[row.header_safe]}}
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. See, don't overthink the issue. Thanks!